# Please recommend a companion for Tesla M40 graphic card

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard

I'd like to buy a NVIDIA Tesla M40 card, but it doesn't have video output, so I need another graphic card to output the graphics rendered by M40. I don't really like to choose an integrated GPU coming with the CPU, so it would be great if you can recommend a separate graphic card that is cheap and yet powerful enough for the job.

Also it would be great if you can also recommend a mainboard that is compatible to Intel Xeon E5 newer CPUs and could meet the requirements for the two cards.